# Replace whole line of first encounter of a single letter using sed

Tags: sed

Consider the following example:

```
[user]$ cat bla.bla
double a=4;
double n=5;
double b=(a/n);
```

If I perform:

```
[user]$sed "a/c\ int a=4;" bla.bla
int a=4;
double n=5;
int a=4;
```

I wish to get as output:

```
[user]$ cat bla.bla
int a=4;
double n=5;
double b=(a/n);
```

Using the sed command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use like this.

```
sed '/^double a/c\int a=4;' file
```

(OR)

```
sed '/^double a=4/c\int a=4;' file
```

**Update:**

```
sed '/ a *=/c\int a=4;' file
```

Comment: it does'nt work ... I also don't want to have the "double" there, only when it recognizes the letter "a"

Comment: Why the downvote?  This is a perfectly reasonable guess at what the OP wanted and, at least with GNU sed, the code works. +1.

Comment: @jarhead Try: `sed '/^[[:alnum:]]* a=/c\int a=4;'`

Comment: @john1024, this won't work if the line will contain  'const double a=4; instead of 'double a'. I'm looking for something generic, recognize a letter or word in text, replace whole line and only that line with new text and finish.

Comment: _"this won't work if the line will contain 'const double a=4"_  These are the kinds of things that one should think about and mention when writing up a question.

Comment: @John1024, drink a cup of water